# Build Name Setter before SCM on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, plugins

I'm using Build Name Setter plugin on Jenkins and it works great.
I'm running latest Jenkins version (2.73.1)

The only problem is that I want it to set the build name before the SCM runs as my SCM operation itself can take 20 minutes and I want to see the build name before then.  It currently only runs after SCM and before actual build steps.

Is there a way to run the plugin before SCM or is there an alternative method to setting the build name in a pre-SCM build step?

Answer (score 1):

```java
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('init'){
            steps {
                script {
                    currentBuild.displayName = "#${BUILD_NUMBER}, blablaaaa1"
                    currentBuild.description = "#${BUILD_NUMBER}, blablaaaa2"
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Git') {
             steps {
                echo "git ..."
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Stephen, thanks for the solution for pipeline. Unfortunately I have to use FreeStyle job as pipeline doesn't support TFS SCM.  Do you know of a solution for FreeStyle jobs as well?